# executing script after jQuery Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I load some HTML code into a div with the .load function af jQuery that contains some code I want to execute;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        //.....
   }
 });
```

After loading the ajax request the alert(); function works, but the the someFunction won't.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('TEST'); //this works
    someFunction("#debug",'var');//this doesn't
});
```

How can I execute this function from an Ajax call

A function executed as `<a onclick="someFunction()"` won't work either.

Comment: Do you mean to execute JS appending from the ajax content, or execute a function after the ajax call and appending is done?

Comment: where is `someFunction` defined?

Comment: someFunction is defined in a .js files in the page that calls the ajax request.
There's HTML loaded into an DIV that calls the function

Comment: you are loading <script> AND html into a <div> and expecting 'document' ready to trigger?

Comment: Looks like `someFunction` may have problematic code.  Can we see it?

Comment: can you show an online example of the page?

Comment: Yes and the document' ready trigges and executes the alert(); but doesn't execute the 'someFunction'

Comment: the some function works because it is executing the call (its on a local server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should use [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to loading some javascript from the server and execute it.

**UPDATED:**
In the most cases one load only the pure HTML fragment with respect of `jQuery.ajax`. Binding of elements to some javascript functions one do inside of `success` handle. All functions which one use in any event handler one loaded before (with `<script>` in the `<head>` block) on the main page (on the page which call `jQuery.ajax`). Then all look very clear and dynamic loading of any scripts is not needed.

Comment: Why should I do that, if the javascript is already present in the document that call the new HTML

Comment: You should look which `data` you have inside of `success` handler of `jQuery.ajax`. Probably you want use `jQuery.load` (see http://api.jquery.com/load/). `jQuery.ajax` will be **not** used for page redirection, but for inserting or modifying some parts of existing HTML page. So `<head>` part of html page will not be loaded. Moreover it is better to prepare html code **fragments** which will be loaded per ajax instead of using full existing html pages.

Comment: hmmm, oké I'll try that. So its not possible?

Comment: Well, I do not load comple pages I just load some HTML without the head, body etc... the loaded HTML just call the some javascript functions.

Comment: all is possible. But you should load html code fragment with `jQuery.load` and then either had already all scripts loaded before or load and execute the code per `jQuery.getScript` after the new html already loaded. In general you should not use existing full html pages, but **prepare** html fragments and seldom javascript code specially for loading per ajax.

Comment: The html which you load per ajax should have no `onclick="someFunction()"` construction. You should use `jQuery.bind`, `jQuery.live` etc instead.

Comment: $('a#foo').bind('click', function() {alert('<a> with id="foo" are clicked');}); (see http://api.jquery.com/bind/ for more examples) or $('a#foo').live('click', function() {alert('<a> with id="foo" are clicked');}); The main advantage of `jQuery.live` is that you can attach a handler to an element which is not yet exist (it will be loaded per ajax for example later). See http://api.jquery.com/live/ for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks fot showing me that wat I wanted is not a good approach! I've learnd something today!

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use the callback function that's already available in your ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
dataType: "html",
success: function(data){
    alert('TEST'); //this works
    someFunction("#debug",'var');//this doesn't
}});
```

I would take a closer look at how you are architecting the code