# Initialize script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to learn how to initialize scripts. I have google it but dont dont really understand it.

Right now I have a toggle-script that is in a div, that entire div gets loaded in to another page. The toggle scripts work, but not when its loaded in.

```
$(".class").click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("add_class");
});
```

If somebody have time, can you explain to me how to initialize this script?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using .live("click", function()...) instead of .click() ?

Comment: @Thomas [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

You should put this script inside a document.ready call.

Eg.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Put your code here
});
```

If I misunderstood your question and what you actually mean is:

How do you execute the script after you load it in through an AJAX call.
Then see this question: [executing script after jQuery Ajax Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514096/executing-script-after-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: This will not fix the issue for dynamically added elements.

Comment: It wouldn't but I am not sure exactly what the OP is after as he mentions the div being loaded into another page

Comment: I meant how to execute it after its been loaded in via jQuery load, cant get it to work.

Comment: I would suggest putting that in the question

Comment: But issent that the same thing as initialize the script?

Comment: initialize the script could refer to a lot of different things :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling it after the elements are loaded on the page?

You should be using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with jQuery 1.7+

```
$(document).on("click", ".class", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("add_class");
});
```

If you want to keep your syntax, you would have to do it either after the elements are rendered, or do it on document.ready.

Comment: you should also suggest narrowing down the container from `document` to some container.

Comment: I load a div containing the toggleclass into page, the on() dident work. Do you have any other idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Wobot can you update your question with the `on()` code you tried? it should work.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sqhzN/, You need to show code that "fails" if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

I figure you're using jquery.ajax to fetch the div?

If so, you should be able to add the listeners in the success-function of the jquery.ajax call:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  $("#result .class").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("add_class");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simple and best

```
$(function(){
    //your code here...
    $(".class").click(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("add_class");
    });
});
```