# Execute script after loaded in div

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Initialize script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991246/initialize-script)

I have a page (Page1.html) and in this page a div (#div1) that get its content from other divs in another page (Page2 #div1/2/3/4/5). The content is loaded in by jQuery load script. The content is loaded in based on choice in a select box, so the content is loaded in after Page1 has finish loaded.

**Problem:**
When I get some content from Page2 that's depending on jQuery, these elements don't work. They don't execute.

**My questions:**
Is there any way to make the a whole inloaded #div from Page2 (all the content) to execute WHEN its loaded in? Right now the existing elements "initialize" when they are loaded in, for example: function initializeSlider(){ slider };.

Now I am trying to add in some more elements depending on jQuery, and wounder if initializing all the objects is the correct way of execute all these scripts, or is there any way that execute all the jQuery elements at once so no need to initializing all object one by one?

**Executing or Initializing one script:**
If there is no way to execute/initialize all scripts at once when a div is loaded in. I am trying to execute or initialize this script without success, have tried both the "$(document).ready(function() {" and initialize it similar to the slider but the element is not executing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lil").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

Comment: Do a search for "delegated event handler".

Comment: Please stop asking duplicate questions. You should edit existing questions instead of asking new, duplicate ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").on('click', '.lil', function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey this one worked! Thanks! Can you explain it?

Comment: jquery click() is only binded to those dom elements which are already loaded before jquery ready function is called. To bind dom elements which are loaded via ajax, you have to use on() function. Just make sure that the parent element (#div1 in your case) should be present before ready function is called.

Comment: So with this solution the element is loaded in when Page1 is loaded? Or is that wrong?

Comment: You don't have to worry much, this will work for you. If you don't have a parent element you can use $(document) in place of $("#div1")

Comment: But does the element load when Page1 is loaded or when the load script load content from Page2? The ($document) solution dont work for me, should it do that?

Comment: on() binds the existing elements as well as elements which are loaded via ajax

Comment: Ok. I think I understand the basic meaning of on() but probably google have the rest of the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21522/discussion-between-vivek-and-wobot)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're initializing; for events make sure and use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#div1").on('click', '.lil', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give that function a name. Something like:

```
function toggleClasses(classToToggle) {
    $(classToToggle).click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
}
```

Then, your main page could have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    toggleClasses('.lil');
});
```

And at the bottom of the partial view that you load from page 2, add this:

```
<script>
    toggleClasses('.partialViewClass');
</script>
```

That way, as soon as that Partial View is done loading, it will call that same function.

If all you're doing is toggling that class, you might want to add a parameter for a secondary class to differentiate the elements in the partial view from the elements in the original page, that way the ones in the original page won't get toggled back when the partial view gets loaded.

So the ones in your partial view would need the highlight class as well as that secondary differentiation class (class="lil partialViewClass"). Pass the class as the parameter to the function so each one will only toggle what it should.